# Cloud Router limitations

Tags: google-cloud-router

I am working on a Google Cloud Platform design where we are going to have several Partner Interconnect from multiple MPLS networks which needs to be isolated.

In the following link it is mentioned that a region can have up to 5 Cloud Routers, it is not very clear if there are limits per VPC, project or region wide.

https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/router-quotas

We will in fact have more then 10 Cloud Routers, is this supported in the same region and same project but different VPC networks?

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider cloud routers per project  [quota](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#per_project), and request an increase according to your needs.

Regarding your question, this  [link](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/router-quotas)
let us know that we can create up to five CR in given VPC and region.
So the answer is "yes you can but you may need a cloud router per project quota increase".

Hope this helps.

Update: As shown in the image, I was able to create 10 cloud routers, same region, 5 under a VPC.
[image]